# GAEアプリケーションのdeployでサーバ証明書エラー

Tags: google-app-engine

GAEアプリケーション作成 初心者のものです。

「Hellow World」 を表示するだけの
簡単なGAE/Goアプリケーションをdeployしようと試みたのですが、
deploy時に以下のエラーが表示されました。

[エラー内容]

```
httplib2.SSLHandshakeError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
error while running appcfg.py: exit status 1
```

エラー番号`14090086`を調べてみたところ、
①サーバ側の証明書が不正（有効期限切れorもともと認証局によって正当性が担保されていない、等）
②クライアント側にインストールされているルート証明書が不正（有効期限切れ等）
等の原因が挙げられていました。

他者のパソコンでは、deployできたため、
②が原因でサーバ証明書の検証が出来なかったと考えております。

また、以下で同様の問題の解決策として、
`google_appengine/lib/cacerts/cacerts.txt`を削除するとあったのですが、改善されませんでした。

何か、他に打つ手はないでしょうか。

[類似]
[Stack Overflow - GAE SDK 1.7.4 and InvalidCertificateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899530/gae-sdk-1-7-4-and-invalidcertificateexception)

[環境]

- Windows 7 32bit
- Python 2.7.5
- go_appengine_sdk_windows_386-1.9.53